# FactoryGirl.create issues "LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)" with Rails 5

Tags: factory-bot, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm in the process of upgrading my app to Rails 5
When running the tests with rails 5 enabled I started to get "LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)" on several object creation sentences like this one:

```
let!(:entity) { create(:entity) }
```

This started to happen after I upgraded to Rails 5.0.0 
I tried using build instead of create on that line and the error doesn't show up in that case.

Has anyone got a similar issue?

My Entity factory is this one:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :entity do
    entity_type 'A'
    account { create(:account) }
    ilk []
    after(:build) do |entity|
      entity.names << build(:name)
      entity.addresses << build(:address)
    end

    trait :incomplete do
      incomplete true
    end
  end
```

My Gemfile looks like this: https://jpst.it/Lb6N

**EDIT**

I found out the issue is not with FactoryGirl but with Mongoid gem. I opened a ticket on JIRA for that project. Here's the link but you'll need to have an account with access to Mongoid project at JIRA: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOID-4302

The details of this ticket are that by running rspec -b to see the trace, I identified the issue on this line on the mongoid gem:

https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/clients/options.rb#L25

The issue disappears if I replace that line (yield self) with just:

self

I'm not sure however if this is a feasible fix, so I opened the ticket mentioned before to get mongoid's feedback and see what can be done.

I'll update again when I get any feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I found the source of the issue on a local fork of the mongoid_token gem, which was causing this weird problem. Mongoid and FactoryGirl gems are not related to this issue, neither the original mongoid-token gem.